# Why does Chrome audit recommend me to minimize cookie size?

Tags: performance, google-chrome, browser, cookies, audit

How can I minimize cookie size of my requests? Chrome seems to 'warn me' about my cookie size being 41B, which is not a lot at all, but is there a reason it warns me about it?

It is a PHPSESSID cookie, which I do not really know how to minimize. Any ideas?

My request responses themselves should already be Gzipped, but from what I know it is not possible to compress headers themselves, or is there?

Thanks! I'm just a little OCD about performance and audits that tell me I could do something better.

Comment: Well, that one simply ignores the cookie size issue from the audit, it doesn't really answer my question about why Chrome warns me about it and what to do to not be warned.

Answer (score 25):

The Chrome Audit tool issues this warning *incorrectly*. 41B is a small cookie and will easily fit in the MTU of 1500B.

For example, if you run Audit against Google.com, it will complain about their 104B cookie. The Chrome team need to fix this erroneous warning, but you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: Downvoted. Please let us know what a suitably small cookie would be? 1 byte?