# How to minimize cookie size in TYPO3?

Tags: cookies, typo3, google-chrome-devtools, typoscript

When executing the chrome dev tool audit for my TYPO3 site, Chrome gives the following warning:

> **Minimize cookie size**
>   The average cookie size for all requests on this page is 40 B

Is there a way to reduce cookie size in TYPO3 via typoscript, .htaccess or other functions?

EDIT:

I know about the fact that the chrome devtool warning is incorrect. But I still need the information if the size of the cookies can be reduced via TYPO3.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Chrome audit recommend me to minimize cookie size?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10105602/why-does-chrome-audit-recommend-me-to-minimize-cookie-size)

Comment: which cookies are set and what information do they contain? It depends on what you are using cookies for. Have a look with the dev tools and maybe update the question with the concrete cookie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot reduce the cookie size since the TYPO3 `fe_typo_user` cookie by default only includes the session ID. You can't get that any smaller.

What you could do is referencing the assets (images, css, javascript) from a different domain (`assets.example.org`). The TYPO3 cookie will then not be transmitted to this different domain.

Comment: If you don't have any frontend login. You can disable the `fe_typo_user` cookie. Also you can disable the cookie as long as no data is saved to the session, e.g. a login.